# PayPal Website Payments Standard API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I assume the answer to this is in the PayPal documentation somewhere, but I've been reading it for two days and my eyes are beginning to whirl.

For Website Payments Standard, I create a page on my site (let's call this **page A**) which contains a dynamically generated form which contains a bunch of hidden fields detailing the content of the cart, prices of each item included, etc. It also has a token to identify the seller id. And one visible form element: the submit image.

The customer clicks the image, which submits the form to PayPal. PayPal do their thing (which includes posting some data back to us at a URL we define (let's call this **page B**)), and then returns the customer back to us (again at a URL we define (let's call this **page C**)).

What I'm looking for is some sort of transaction ID. We have hits from the user on pages **A** and **C**, and a hit from PayPal on page **B**. How do we know these three hits apply to the same transaction? (The hit on page **C** may not happen, of course.)

---

In a separate question, am I the only one who thinks PayPal documentation is confusingly written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can already identify **A** and **C** as the same user by means of the session ID. And, on **A**, we can set a form field called **custom** containing any information we like. This will be posted back, unchanged, by PayPal to page **B**. This can be used to identify the user there.